# Unable to see X-cache in Respomse Header

Tags: caching, httpresponse, varnish, xcache

I want to check whether a page view on localhost encountered a cache hit or a cache miss. I'm running varnish on my local machine. Next, I wanna check the X-cache header in response. But I cant see any X-cache tag in the response header. i'm able to see server, Etag, x-runtime et. , but not X-cache

How can I see the X-cache?

Answer (score 0):

By adding it;

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it seems it doesn't arrive at vcl_deliver, which as far as I know  only can mean that you deliver with pipe